# Bootstrapped Fileinput with JS (in PHP)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to create a page for sending issues.
Therefore people may want to upload an image with the issue.
The whole page uses bootstrap.
I had a look on Google and liked https://codepen.io/claviska/pen/vAgmd most. The last solution seemed nice.
But I don't get the file name in the text box.
What am I doing wrong?
I used the code shown in the pen:

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="files">Select some screenshots to append</label>
<div class="input-group">
<span class="input-group-btn">
<span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
Browse&hellip;
<input type="file" name="files" single>
</span>
</span>
<input type="text" class="form-control" readonly>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {

    // We can attach the `fileselect` event to all file inputs on the page
    $(document).on('change', ':file', function() {
        var input = $(this),
            numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
            label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
    });

    // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(':file').on('fileselect', function(event, numFiles, label) {

            var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

            if (input.length) {
                input.val(log);
            } else {
                if (log) alert(log);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

My full page: http://gelbpunkt.troet.org/browsercheck/issue.php
Bootstrap is included, as well as jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the value of the input field in where the alert is, but first give the input field an ID like *fileName*:

```
<input type="text" id="fileName" class="form-control" readonly>
```

Then in your jquery, remove the alert and set the file name there:

```
if( log ){
  //alert(log);
  $("#fileName").val(log);
}
```

See [sample](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dVmjOM)

Comment: Yeah, that works. I am using bootstrap-fileinput by now, that works as well and even better. Thanks for your answer, I accepted it.